# Issue of getting image from web public folder in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, url, host

Hii Friends I have facing one problem in my virtually setup symfony project. When I want to try fetching image which is placed in web/uploads/images/ folder then i am getting this error. "No route found for "GET /uploads/images/2.jpeg".

[image: Image for showing error message]

My controller work is fine but problem is that i can't fetching any public file from web folder.

You can also check my virtual setup code in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot D:/XAMPP/htdocs/symphony/web/app_dev.php
  ServerName symphony.com
  <Directory D:/XAMPP/htdocs/symphony/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Check my file where i want get that image.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h2>Todo Edit</h2>
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}


<img src="{{ url('todo_list') }}uploads/images/2.jpeg" />

{{form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

Also check image for that file.
[image: Image of file where i am fetching image code.]

Comment: You are showing the code that actually sends your error.  Please post your code snippet from where you trying to obtain the image from.

Comment: @Joseph_J please check my question that i have updated according your suggestion.

Comment: I would start by verifying that {{ url('todo_list') }}uploads/images/2.jpeg" forms a correct path to your image.

Comment: Yes this is getting URL of home page from route setting function in my controller.

    `/**
     * @Route("/", name="todo_list")
     */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use assets:

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
   <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

You can read here for more info: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: Thanks for your help i have solved this problem after so much stuff with successfully installed assets because for that i have manually added 
`templating:
        engines: ['twig']` in config.yml file then i have solved this issue.

Comment: there are way to get real name of that js file after executing this code. because i am getting that file in with some random number so i think this is going in problem in SEO.

Comment: `{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/uploads/images/5498a17e75d686c89e43ccc6583ab100.jpeg'  %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endimage %}` check this is my code but i am getting output image  link is like `<img src="/images/8ec46a7_5498a17e75d686c89e43ccc6583ab100_1.jpeg">`

Comment: Can you try: {{ asset('bundles/bundle_name_with_lower_case_without_Bundle_sufix(AppBundle->app)/images/IMAGE_NAME.jpeg')}}